# Complex Number Proof using vectors

Tags: complex-numbers

Hey i've been stuck on this proof for a bit, I was wondering in (2), do you use the x axis as along the vector $w_0$ as they used to get the equation for $p$, and if so, how to get the other expressions for q, r, and s, or would $s=(-w_3/2-i(w_3)/2)$ for example be right ?
thank you

Comment: It was about three years ago that the gift of divination was taken away from all the members of mathematics exchange, and since then we need all the data explicitly written down in the questions: what is (2), what is $\;w_0\;$ , what are $\;p,q,r,s\;$ ...? In short: what in the world are you talking about?!

Comment: My bad, link didn't work, try this one: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UwqvE_ANR5MnRXRmhHNlRYeXM

Comment: Ok, then yes: it seems to be be that, in a rather unexplained and unjustified way, whoever wrote that exercise assumes $\;w_0\;$ in on the real axis, and thus the expression for $\;p\;$ is correct. Why do they assume that? I've no idea....and if they assume that, why don't they say it explicitly? Again, I've no idea...